# make pod resolve external service name via DNS

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, coredns

I have a client applicationg running in a pod, on kubernetes 1.11.1., that should connect to a rabbitMQ cluster.

I would like to create a service that should round robin among two IP addresses of two hosts. The hosts are not pods, they are external virtual machines acting as a cluster of rabbitMQ.

I created a service and an endpoint that share the name (rabbitmq-service) in order to match. Now, from a pod it is not possibile to resolve via DNS the servicename.default.svc, while it is possible to resolve both host names via a name that contains the service name, as in: N-N-N-N.servicename.namespace.svc.clusterdomain. (where N-N-N-N is similar to an ip address).

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
```

endpoints.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
  namespace: default
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.112.63.98
      - ip: 10.112.63.99
    ports:
    - name: http
      port: 5672
      protocol: TCP
```

How can I configure the servicename.default.svc resolution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I applied your configurations and this is what I get:

```
kubectl get endpoints
NAME               ENDPOINTS                             AGE
kubernetes         192.168.99.116:8443                   45s
rabbitmq-service   10.112.63.98:5672,10.112.63.99:5672   13s
```

Also I tried to resolve the dns of rabbitmq-service from another pod using the below commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup rabbitmq-service.default
```

The above `nslookup` command in the pod gave the output:

```
Defaulting container name to busybox.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/busybox -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local


Name:      rabbitmq-service.default
Address 1: 10.101.126.122 rabbitmq-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

which means that the service is resolvable. I hope there should be problem in accessing your rabbitmq service from your machines running the kubernetes cluster.

Please refer to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) document if you suspect an issue with kubernetes coreDNS.

Comment: Indeed the DNS seems to be working. Still, if we connect using the service name, we get an error from the AMQP client library, while connecting using the direct address of any rabbitmq server works. See:
`amqp-get --url amqp://user:pwd@rabbitmq-service.default:5672/prod --queue prova` gives error `logging in to AMQP server: invalid AMQP data`, while `amqp-get --url amqp://user:pwd@10-112-63-98.rabbitmq-service.default:5672/prod --queue prova` works. Using `strace` I found that the first connection is routed to the wrong (HTTP) port of rabbitmq, while the second goes to AMQP port.

Comment: Removing "name: http" from service and endpoints, solved the problem. It seems that specifying "name: http" forced the service protocol to HTTP.

Comment: Me too suspected the same.